# SparkR : how to acces files passed with --files in yarn-cluster mode

Tags: r, apache-spark, pyspark, sparkr

I am sending a sparkR Job to run on a Yarn cluster in `cluster mode` with `./bin/spark-submit` script. I need to upload a file (external dataset) by the `--file` option. This action upload files to HDFS tempory directory. But I need to access to the path where the file was downloaded to include it directly in my SparkR code.

For [java](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html) and [PySpark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.html), files distributed using --files can be accessed via `SparkFiles.get(filename)` method which return the absolute path of `filename`. **Is there an equivalent in SparkR ?**

I know we can work around the problem by different ways :

- Put files manualy to HDFS
- Deploy files on worker nodes

But I want to use this option for convinient reasons.

Comment: There is no SparkR equivalent. Given __public__ SparkR API there is really no context in which you could use it.

Comment: You can easly have to integrate a non-bulky external file to perform periodic additional analysis on your principal data base stored on HDFS.

Comment: I reckon you use internal RDD API? Because otherwise there is no way you could use these from R without building Scala wrapper first.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you first answer. Do you think it could be a good functionality to develop for SparkR ?

Comment: Well, first we'll need a new, low(er) level API and this is still an ongoing process. The answers on its performance and  the final shape.